Create Saved Audience using Facebook Ads API
I need to create a Saved Audience so that I can use them for other AdSets. Refer here.
I found the documentation to read the Saved Audiences available in an ad account. But Create operation is not supported for this endpoint. How to create a Saved Audience using API?
